# Obtengo este error: RequestError: Invalid column name 'undefined' una y otra vez

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy trabajando en un CRUD de practica usando Node, pero unicamente funciona mi metodo get, el resto siempre tiene el mismo resultado: RequestError: Invalid column name 'undefined'.

En la terminal se suele verasí con cada metodo: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Leí en otro post que la solución era cambiar 'req.query' a 'req.params'pero no me funciono, el resultado fue el mismo y deje el código como estaba originalmente. Aqui desconozco si fue un problema de implementación o simplemente mi error está en otra parte del código

Mi controlador es este:

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const dbConfig = require('../database/dbConfig');


const getProveedores = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await sql.connect(dbConfig);

    const result = await sql.query('SELECT * FROM proveedor');

    res.json(result.recordset);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al obtener los proveedores', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error al obtener los proveedores' });
  } 
};

const guardarProveedor = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { nombre, direccion, telefono, estado } = req.body;

    await sql.connect(dbConfig);

    await sql.query(
      `INSERT INTO proveedor (Nombre, Dirección, Telefono, Estado) VALUES ('${nombre}', '${direccion}', '${telefono}', ${estado})`
    );

    res.status(201).json({ message: 'Proveedor guardado exitosamente' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error al guardar el proveedor', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error al guardar el proveedor' });
  }
};
```

En mi vista tengo el siguiente script:

```
<script>
  const proveedoresTableBody = document.getElementById('proveedores-table-body');

  function obtenerProveedores() {
    fetch('/proveedores')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(proveedores => {
        proveedoresTableBody.innerHTML = '';

        proveedores.forEach(proveedor => {
          const row = document.createElement('tr');
          row.innerHTML = `
            <td>${proveedor.Id_Proveedor}</td>
            <td>${proveedor.Nombre}</td>
            <td>${proveedor.Dirección}</td>
            <td>${proveedor.Telefono}</td>
            <td>${proveedor.Estado}</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editarModal" onclick="editarProveedor(${proveedor.Id_Proveedor})">Editar</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#eliminarModal" onclick="eliminarProveedor(${proveedor.Id_Proveedor})">Eliminar</button>
            </td>
          `;
          proveedoresTableBody.appendChild(row);
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error al obtener los proveedores', error);
      });
  }

  obtenerProveedores();

  // Guardado
  document.getElementById('proveedorForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    const direccion = document.getElementById('direccion').value;
    const telefono = document.getElementById('telefono').value;
    const estado = document.getElementById('estado').value;
    const proveedor = {
      nombre,
      direccion,
      telefono,
      estado
    };

    fetch('/proveedores', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(proveedor)
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Proveedor guardado exitosamente', response);
        // Limpiar los campos del formulario
        document.getElementById('nombre').value = '';
        document.getElementById('direccion').value = '';
        document.getElementById('telefono').value = '';
        document.getElementById('estado').value = '';

        obtenerProveedores();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error al guardar el proveedor', error);
      });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el esquema de la tabla donde quieres insertar? Me sorprende ver el nombre de una columna con tilde, suele ser contraproducente.

Comment: Claro, mi tabla es esta:  [dbo].[proveedor](
 [Id_Proveedor] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Nombre] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Dirección] [varchar](100) NULL,
 [Telefono] [varchar](10) NULL,
 [Estado] [int] NOT NULL,

Como es una práctica, la base de datos venía así por defecto y realmente olvidé cambiarlo a algo más practico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el problema es causado porque no comruebas los datos a insertar:

```
INSERT INTO proveedor (Nombre, Dirección, Telefono, Estado)
 VALUES ('${nombre}', '${direccion}', '${telefono}', ${estado})
```

La última columna no está entrecomillada y, si el valor de `estado` es `undefined`, SQL asume que quieres insertar ahí el valor de otra columna llamada `undefined`. Puesto que ese valor no es *nullable*, deberías quizá sustituirlo por un 0 u otro valor por defecto o directamente devolver un error por no tener un valor válido.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no lo había notado. Agregue las comillas y funcionó sin necesidad de agregarle un valor predeterminado al estado.